# What is "Exception Thrown" in C/C++?

Tags: c

I don't understand what's wrong with this simple code.
Why does the error occur in

```
int x = D[i]; D[i] = D[j]; D[j] = x;
```

Here is my code

```c
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int D[10] = { 58,12,39,90,49,26,68,47,15,39 };
int n = 10;

void printArray(int A[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { printf("%3d", A[i]); }
    printf("\n");
}

void swapD(int i, int j)
{
    int x = D[i]; D[i] = D[j]; D[j] = x;
}

int partition(int left, int right)
{
    int i = left, j = right-1;
    int k = (left + right) / 2;
    printf("from %3d to %3d, %4d:", D[left], D[right], D[k]);
    
    swapD(k, right);
    while (i <= j) {
        while (D[i] < D[right]) i++;
        while (D[j] >= D[right] && j>=i ) j--;
        if (i < j)
            swapD(i, j);
    }
    swapD(i, right);
    printArray(D);
    
    return i;
}

void quicksort(int left, int right)
{
    int i = partition(left, right);
    if (i <= right) {
        quicksort(left, i-1);
        quicksort(i+1, right);
    }
}

void main()
{
    printf("\n%22s","");
    printArray(D);
    quicksort(0, n - 1);
    _getch();
}
```

It's about the quick sort.
I can't build-up this in my way. because of it's kinda homework..
Thank you! :)

Comment: Exceptions are not a part of C per se — not standard C, anyway.  If you get an exception, your code did something wrong.  For the snippet you quote, it's virtually guaranteed that `i` or `j` or both are out of control — has some bogus value.

Comment: C language has no notion of Exception. The relevant part of the error message is `Access violation writing...`. It is a hint that you are probably trying to write outside of an array (past last element). It can also happen if you have inkoked Undefined Behaviour elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Well, this loop looks suspicious, for example: `while (D[i] < D[right]) i++;` - how do you know it will ever terminate (an will in the array bounds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception being thrown is `Access violation writing to ...`

Meaning you are trying to write to a memory location that you're not allowed to, i.e, you didn't allocate it.

If you use the debugger and go step by step into your code, you would see that after a few iterations

```
swapD(k, right);
```

is called with `k=0`, `right=-1`
which in turn would call

```
D[-1] = x;
```

which mean you're trying to access an invalid location.

you should always access array elements after you've verified that the indices are not larger than the last element index or smaller than the first element's index

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea how to access in the recursive function at debuger.. When I push f11, I doesn't go in to the fuction again..

Comment: At least you tried; this is already more than 60% of people are willing to do! You might want to ask a separate question on the Visual Studio's debugging process, if it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: @Sion, make sure you're using the Debug configuration and not the Release, it should allow you to move into the function when debugging

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms, suppose you have an `int` array of 5 elements:

```
int array[5];
```

If you try to access (read or write) an element that's greater than 4(index of array starts at 0), you will get this exception. It basically means that you tried to access a memory that you weren't allowed to.

In the code below, the value of `i` or `j` is greater than the size of the array, hence the exception.

```c
void swapD(int i, int j)
{
    int x = D[i]; D[i] = D[j]; D[j] = x;
}
```

On linux, you get `segmentation fault` if you try something like this.

Try playing with this small program:

```c
int main()
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int x = a[4]; //bad
    int y = a[-1]; //very bad
    int z = a[3]; //bad

    int good = a[0];
}
```